# Django password fields placeholder

Tags: django

I try to enable placeholder at my SignUp form with 4 fields: phone, email, password1, password2. For first two fields all correct, but for password field it doesn't work.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from customuser.models import User
from django.forms import TextInput,EmailInput,PasswordInput

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):    


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_client','is_partner')
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email adress'}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone number  +79011234567'}),
            'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password from numbers and letters of the Latin alphabet'}),
            'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '
Password confirmation'}),

        }
```

Answer (score 8):

The `Meta.widgets` option doesn't apply to fields that were declared in the form. See the [note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields). In this case, `password1` and `password2` are declare on the `UserCreationForm` (they aren't model fields), therefore you can't use them in `widgets`.

You could set the widget in the `__init__` method instead:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone', 'email', 'is_client', 'is_partner')
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email adress'}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone number  +79011234567'}),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password from numbers and letters of the Latin alphabet'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password confirmation'})
```

Comment: Hmm, I think this is what I need, but it did not work for me for some reason(

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but I can't spot the problem with it. Hope you manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

This code works fine

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):    
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password from numbers and letters of the Latin alphabet'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password confirm'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_client','is_partner')
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email adress'}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone number format +79011234567'}),


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the @Alasdair ´s solution and work for me this way:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("First name"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _("First name")}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _("Email")}))

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = auth.get_user_model()
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InviteRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': _("Password")})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': _("Password")})
```