# How to apply placeholder attribute on PasswordInput in Django Model Form?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have created a custom registration form. The 'placeholder' attribute works good for the username and email. But it doesn't apply to password1 and password2, to which I mentioned 'forms.PasswordInput'.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        exclude=()
        widgets = {'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username','class':'inputData'}),
                   'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'inputData'}),
                   'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'inputData'}),
                   'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', 'class': 'inputData'})}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django password fields placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413185/django-password-fields-placeholder)

Comment: can you show the template and css

Comment: @SukumarRdjf Thanks. It worked!