# Can't add widget to UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to style my form. And I need to add placeholder to all inputs but can't add placeholder to password1 and password2.

I tried:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

"""
    The registration form that inherits UserCreationForm.
    Fiels:
         ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password_repeat']

    Windgets:
        For all inputs we creates atributte class: .signup_input

"""

class Meta:
    model   = Account
    fields  = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
    widgets = {
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type your username'}),
            'password1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Choose a password'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Confirmar Password'}),
    }
```

this is my model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
"""
    The class Account inherits AbstractBaseUser.
    This is a model for users.
    Fields:
        ['email', 'username', 'date_joined', 'is_active',
        'is_moderator', 'is_admin', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff']


    Model manager is:
        objects = MyAccountManager()

"""
email           = models.EmailField(max_length=20, unique=True, verbose_name='email')
username        = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='date joined')
is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_moderator    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

#What user will put into form
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
```

How can I add placeholder to password1 and password2?
Thanks)

Comment: can you please post code as code and not in pictures?

Comment: @bb4L yeah sorry.

Comment: this should resolve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49413451/13168118